# Avoiding repetition in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

given this data structure (variable in size):

```
items =   [(u'Triathalon ', u' Teenager'), (u'The Airplanes ', u' Paper Hearts'), (u"Holy '57 ", u' Island Kids'), (u'Yohuna ', u' Apart'), (u'Moon Bounce ', u' Shake'), (u'Miami Horror ', u' Wild Motion (Set It Free)'), (u'Colleagues ', u' Somewhere'), (u'Poor Spirits ', u' BwooKlyn'), (u'Air Review ', u' Young'), (u'Radiohead', u'Karma Police')]
```

I would like to do this:

```
if len(items) > 10:
   for artist, track in random.sample(items, 10):
       # do a lot of things in many lines of code
elif len(items) < 10:
   for artist, track in items:
       # do the exact same thing
```

but this is rather redundant.

what is the simplest way of achieving the same result without repeating myself?

Comment: You do realize your existing code doesn't handle the `len(items) == 10` case, right? Presumably, if you do use the code, your `elif` statement should just be an `else` case with no conditional testing.

Comment: well noted, will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
for artist, track in random.sample(items,min(10,len(items))):
# do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Trivial approach is to use `sample` unconditionally, but limit the sample size based on the length of the input (so `sample` just shuffles small inputs without cut down):

```
for artist, track in random.sample(items, min(len(items), 10)):
```

Behaviorally different, since it randomizes small lists too, but you clearly didn't care about ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min` (yes, `min`, not `max`) to set a maximum value.

```
for artist, track in random.sample(items, min(10, len(items))):
```

Alternatively, you can save the iterable you're interested in first:

```
if len(items) > 10:
    i = random.sample(items, 10)
else:
    i = items
for artist, track in i:
```

Note that your code actually has different behavior for `items` of varying lengths, as a longer `items` gets randomly sampled while a shorter one is iterated over in its original order.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice)?

```
import numpy.random as npr

slice = npr.choice(items, 10, replace=False)
for artist, track in slice:
    # do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the random.sample before the common code.

```
items = [...]

if len(items) > 10:
    real_items = random.sample(items, 10):
else:
    real_items = items
```

Then do whatever you are doing with real_items

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
samplesize = 10 if len(items) > 10 else len(items)
sample = random.sample(items, samplesize)
for artist, track in sample:
    ....
```